# Spring Maven Standalone application Jar not working

Tags: spring, maven, resources

I created a Spring standalone application with maven. Hence maven dependencies are also added.

- src folder sturcture is src/main/java resources folder is as
  src/main/resources.
- resources folder contains 1)applicationContext.xml
  2)application.properties.

If i run jar from command line i get following errors

```
 D:\>java -jar "myTest.jar"
Aug 31, 2016 7:20:21 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicat
ionContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationCont
ext@74be95bf: startup date [Wed Aug 31 19:20:21 PKT 2016]; root of context hiera
rchy
Aug 31, 2016 7:20:22 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionR
eader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [resources/applicati
onContext.xml]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.my.sftp.SFTPTester.main(SFTPTester
.java:78)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOExc
eption parsing XML document from class path resource [resources/applicationConte
xt.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
[resources/applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBea
nDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBea
nDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReade
r.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loa
dBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:123)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loa
dBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationCon
text.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtain
FreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:612)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refres
h(AbstractApplicationContext.java:513)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<i
nit>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:197)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<i
nit>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:172)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<i
nit>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:158)
        at com.my.sftp.ApplicationContextProvider.<clinit>(Applicat
ionContextProvider.java:10)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [resources/applica
tionContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPat
hResource.java:172)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBea
nDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
        ... 12 more

    Here are the few lines of pom.xml suggesting how i am adding "resources" folder reference

    <build>
       <resources>
       <resource><directory>src/main/resources</directory></resource>
       </resources>
      <pluginManagement>
       <plugins>
        <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.3.1</version>
         <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>

         </configuration>
        </plugin>
       </plugins>
      </pluginManagement>
```

Here is the main() code

```
public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     ConfigurableApplicationContext context = null;
     try {
       context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("resources/applicationContext.xml", SFTPTester.class);
       context.getBean("sftpTester");

     } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       context.close();
     }
     catch (Throwable t) {
         t.printStackTrace();
         context.close();
       }

   }
```

Current Project structure is given above
[image]

Comment: I think you simply need to open the file "resources/applicationContext.xml" via the resource loader, since it is not available as file (through getClass().getResourceAsStream()....). If you don't try to read or parse it you may just configured the location of the spring-context file wrong? in that case try to remove the resources/ part. Everything in src/main/resources ends up directly in the classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is as it is in the question except changing line referencing to context in java main() solved the issue. Now project is working fine in Eclipse debug as well as with maven generated jar file.
So i changed line as

```
context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

When you jar a file using maven the resource files will be directly at the root level. You have to change `resources/applicationContext.xml` to just `applicationContext.xml` to make it work.

On the side note, If you want to know what is in your Jar file, change the .jar to .zip and extract the contents. You will have a better idea of what is going on.

Comment: If so that means if i had to debug code then i had to place contents of my resources folder in same folder where class having main() resides.
So every time i debug i had to change line of code referencing applicationContext.xml.

Comment: I changed according to http://stackoverflow.com/users/258741/zeus 's
reply. But still error exists. Now i can see my applicationContext.xml at the root while observing jar contents.

Comment: @ALI Could you paste the code that loads the xml file?

Comment: I added the main method referencing applicationContext.xml. Also project structure is provided to follow the location

Comment: @ALI even when debugging you can use the same without the resource/ in the path https://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-hello-world-example/

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it's giving same exception